# How to reset DropDownList Index

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

*Im using vs'12 , C# asp.net MVC-4 - Internet Template, with KendoUI EF Code First*

Logic + **Question**: I have first and 2ndary DropDownLists (cascading ones). So many (2ndarys) will cascade off one ( main ) DropDownList. My goal is to , with script or kendo events to **On main selected index change, change all other kendo DDL's back to index(0)** *The cascading and enabling and all of that works fine, when i switch to another control, they all empty out, but if i were to switch back they retain there values. This is not ideal for my application*

**need to know**

- Main Kendo Control

  ```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Tracts)
      .Name("Tracts")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" }) //, id = "clients"})
      .OptionLabel("Select Tract...")
      .DataTextField("TractName")
      .DataValueField("TractID")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetCascadeTracts", "ImageView");
          });
      })
  ```
- 2ndary Kendo Controls

  ```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.LeaseholdA)
        .Name("LeaseholdA")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
        .OptionLabel("Select LeaseholdA...")
        .DataTextField("LeaseholdA")
        .DataValueField("LeaseholdAID")
        .DataSource(source =>
                {
         source.Read(read =>
                 {
                   read.Action("GetLeaseholdA", "ImageView")
                   .Data("filterFromTracts");
                 })
                .ServerFiltering(true);
         })
              .Enable(false)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .CascadeFrom("Tracts")
  )
  ```

**Attempts**

- 1 + 2 *just tryed the 2 rimmed out section*

  ```
  function TractSelect(e) {

      var dropdownlist = $("#LeaseholdA").data("kendoDropDownList");
      //dropdownlist.SelectedIndex(0)
      dropdownlist.enable(false);

  };
  ```
- *The `selectedindex(0)` attempt did what it was supposed to off the ( change event ) the select even would claim `selectedIndex` doesn't exist*
- *The `enable` worked but when i switched back they remembered where they were. so this was ineffective*

Comment: Not sure I see the exact problem, but did you try to use the change event of the master DDL isntead of using the select event?

Comment: Select event fires before change, this is why i initially thought to change it to select event. But almost seems like change has more functionality seem as thought thats when the controls are enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the .value property of the DropDownList(kendo)

```
var dropdownlist = $("#LeaseholdA").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.value(0);
```

These 2 lines work great

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

the dropdownlist variable has a jquery wrapped element here

try using the below code at the same place

```
function TractSelect(e) {

    var dropdownlist = $("#LeaseholdA").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist[0].selectedIndex = 0; //Code you need to change
    dropdownlist.enable(false);

};
```

This will make sure that you have a html element as in plain simple javascript and YES **SelectedIndex is definitely not a function but property of the HTML element**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and corrections, it look like your answer compiles and runs but fires before the values get re-assigned to the KendoUI DropDownlist by its own script?

Comment: You need to call the script on document ready Jquery documentation will explain the same. Here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: For some reason when i place my code into the `$(document).ready(function () {` my kendoUI controls are no longer mapped to use the `TractSelect` function throught the select event and become plain textboxes. Is there a specific way i need to call another function from `$(document).ready(function () {` or can i just place it inside the codebracket like i have done?

Comment: I think your kendo controls should be initialized on in document ready so that you get control over both (Kendo ui controls and html controls) and should solve the problem

Comment: I am still trying to understand what you are trying to tell me, According to **http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/events.html** they are not throwing the actual control into the Tag. From what i can understand you were asking me to put all my controls and Td and div tags into the script wich seemed correct for `.aspx` -  Html5? but not for `.cshtml` - Razor

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to set the index to 0 using the following:

```
$("#LeaseholdA").val(0);
```

This should set the dropdown to the element with a value of 0 and thus the index.

Or you can use

```
$("#LeaseholdA").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Comment: Same issue as Akshay's answer, just seems to be running all this before the Kendo Code Updates it back to what it was.